# Spring Boot POST request with abstract list property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have a spring boot application that has a Game model which has a list of abstract Die objects. There's multiple dice of different colors that extend this Die class and get created by a factory.
This list gets converted to a string before entering into the database and converted back to die objects when retrieved via a converter class.

However when I make a post request and try to map the requestbody to the game class it tries to instantiate the die list which results in this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `sagrada.model.dice.Die` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
```

Is it possible to use some type of converter or tell it to convert the body to the correct die objects before mapping it to Game?

The Game class:

```
@Entity
public class Game {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "game")
    private List<GamePlayer> gamePlayers;

    @Convert(converter = GameStateConverter.class)
    private GameState state;

    @Convert(converter = GameDiceConverter.class)
    private List<Die> die;

    public List<Die> getDie() {
        return die;
    }

    public void setDie(List<Die> die) {
        this.die = die; 
    }
}
```

The Die Class:

```
public abstract class Die {
    private int value;
    private dieColor color;

    public Die(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public dieColor getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(dieColor color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

The Converter class:

```
public class GameDiceConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<Die>, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<Die> dice) {
        StringBuilder diestring = new StringBuilder();

        for (Die die : dice) {
            String dieColor = die.getColor().toString();
            int dieValue = die.getValue();

            diestring.append(dieColor.charAt(0));
            diestring.append(dieValue);
        }

        return diestring.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Die> convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
        String[] dice = s.split("(?<=\\G.{2})");
        List<Die> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String die : dice) {
            switch (die.charAt(0)) {
                case 'B' -> result.add(new BlueDie(die.charAt(1) - '0'));
                case 'G' -> result.add(new GreenDie(die.charAt(1) - '0'));
                case 'P' -> result.add(new PurpleDie(die.charAt(1) - '0'));
                case 'R' -> result.add(new RedDie(die.charAt(1) - '0'));
                case 'Y' -> result.add(new YellowDie(die.charAt(1) - '0'));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And the request:

```
@PostMapping("/")
    ResponseEntity<EntityModel<Game>> newGame(@RequestBody Game game) {
        game.setState(GameState.NEW);
        Game newGame = repository.save(game);

        return ResponseEntity
                .created(linkTo(methodOn(GameController.class).getGame(newGame.getId())).toUri())
                .body(assembler.toModel(newGame));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "Cannot construct instance of `sagrada.model.dice.Die` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types ..."

indicate "private List die;" cannot be initiated

reason: "Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed"
see also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

suggested change: "public class Die" - remove the Abstract form class , if it is unnecessary

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question